# PNG image not showing up in ReactComponent

Tags: reactjs

I have a footer class as below, which is running fine in my localHost, but when I deployed the code in server then image is not showing up. It simply broken down

```
function Footer() {
    return (
        <div>

            <div style={style}>
                <a href="/"><img src={require('../../assets/images/alti-logo.png')} alt="logo"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

In my local I can able to see the image,

But in server I am seeing something like [image]

Comment: Are you sure your serverside image path is correct ?

Comment: double check the image src path when it is render as html. You can use developer tool.

Comment: I tend to set my paths like './../../assets.......' Idk if it will help.

Comment: Evne path is given correct but it is not resolved. But to solve this I have given base 64 code for an image instead of referring to image path to make it work as of now. But still I don't know why image is not loading up from the given path